# How to write an XPath query to match two attributes?

Tags: xpath

Following Question:

```
<div id="id-74385" class="guest clearfix" style="z-index: 999;">
```

Given above,

If I want a XPath expression with checks both id and class, can we do it w/ 'and' condition LIKE:

```
//div[@id='id-74385'] and div[@class='guest clearfix']
```

Is this correct way? My execution fails here... Please help!

Answer (score 280):

```
//div[@id='...' and @class='...']
```

should do the trick. That's selecting the `div` operators that have *both* attributes of the required value.

It's worth using one of the [online XPath testbeds](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) to try stuff out.

Comment: Many of the online tools demand XML compliance. For HTML, it's easier to test with the browser's XPath implementation. Here's a [code sample](https://gist.github.com/jpaugh/a07b369e41c7ba03e8a729c8cb8cc122), together with a helper function to convert iterators into arrays.

Answer (score 129):

or `//div[@id='id-74385'][@class='guest clearfix']`

Answer (score 42):

Adding to Brian Agnew's answer.

You can also do `//div[@id='..' or @class='...]` and you can have parenthesized expressions inside `//div[@id='..' and (@class='a' or @class='b')]`.

Comment: Please note, it should be lowercase. It won't work with uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Sample XML:

```
<X>
<Y ATTRIB1=attrib1_value ATTRIB2=attrib2_value/>
</X>

string xPath="/" + X + "/" + Y +
"[@" + ATTRIB1 + "='" + attrib1_value + "']" +
"[@" + ATTRIB2 + "='" + attrib2_value + "']"
```

XPath Testbed:
http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm