# Selenium select element with multiple attributes

Tags: selenium

How do I select a div using both it's id and class in Selenium firefox addon?

EDIT: I managed to solve it, I used an xpath expression with both the attributes @id=  and @class =

Comment: Care to share the HTML of the div?

Comment: When would one ever need to select on multiple criteria, if id is one of them?

Comment: @KjetilNordin eg: to find whether the element is hidden or not in css

Answer (score -11, accepted):

I managed to solve it, I used an xpath expression with both the attributes @id= and @class =

Comment: Well done for fixing it; for the benefit of people reading the site, can you post your whole solution in the answer, and mark it as accepted?

Comment: Please post whole sol'n.

Answer (score 34):

I stumbled upon this question and thought I would leave an example of the answer that the OP didn't leave (as requested by vincebowdren above):

```
//*/fieldset[@class="openable"][@id="activityFieldset"]
```

This would select a fieldset element with the openeable class and activityFieldset id.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post another correct answer for future reference.

First of all there have been other correct answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42996525/6569715

A valid example would be to define a locator by multiple attributes:

```
HEADER_1_TEXT = (
       By.XPATH, 
       "//h2[@class='text-primary' and @id='my-id' and text() ='Get started with Us']")
```