# Find table id with multiple attributes

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, automated-tests

I'm trying to find attribute using find_element_by_xpath with multiple attributes.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="idMainGridhistoryHeader" border="0" class="adodb_dbgrid" qhelp="2.2_zahlavisloupce">
...
</table>

<table id="idMainGridhistory" agname="history" userid="1" entityidcolumnname="hi_id" editable="1" border="0" class="adodb_dbgrid" scrollx="0">
... # id I want to find idMainGridhistory
</table>
```

I was tried [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/8wFpuiAUGLk):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'adodb_dbgrid') and contains(@userid, '1')]").get_attribute('id')
```

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026766/selenium-select-element-with-multiple-attributes):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='adodb_dbgrid'][@userid='1']").get_attribute('id')
```

but everything will return Unable to locate element. Any advice how to find it with multiple elements?

Comment: `"//table[@class='adodb_dbgrid'][@userid='1']"` this `xpath` means that your element has both attributes, but those attributes belongs to different elements... Clarify what exactly you want to do

Comment: that element table has attributes id="idMainGridhistory" agname="history" userid="1" entityidcolumnname="hi_id" editable="1" border="0" class="adodb_dbgrid" scrollx="0" (In that second table. First table is just reason why I can't find it by one parameter).

Comment: My fail was in bad choose of parameter userid='1'. userid is parameter, that is variable. With other parameter for ex. editable='1' it works

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of other ways how to find second table. Choose one you more like:
1. From list of tables by index

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('table')[1].get_attribute('id')
```

2. By original attribute

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@userid="1"]').get_attribute('id')
```

3. More specific

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@agname="history"][@class="adodb_dbgrid"]').get_attribute('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='adodb_dbgrid'and @userid='1']").get_attribute('id')
```

Comment: My fail was in bad choose of parameter userid='1'. userid is parameter, that is variable. With other parameter for ex. editable='1' it works. But thx.